# How can I get the new 14.04 lock screen back?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

For some reason my lock screen changed a while ago from the new one introduced in 14.04 to the one used in older versions. I'm not sure what I may have done to have caused this.

How can I get the new one back?

Comment: Perhaps you can follow the steps to get the old lock screen shown in http://linuxg.net/how-to-get-the-old-ubuntu-lockscreen-on-your-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/, and choose Unity instead of LightDM.

Comment: @muru I've tried this, apparently the feature to choose between the two was removed before 14.04's release.

Comment: Have you used a tweak tool at all?

Comment: @Tim Hmm, when I first installed Ubuntu I installed some gesture support tools to try and make better use of my laptop's touch screen, now that I think about it, it seems quite likely one of them affected this as I seem to recall the lock screen changing around the same time.

Comment: That's what happened to me - a tweak tool. I uninstalled and it worked - but I guess you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Tim Well, I never got the ones I tried working, so I'll go back and uninstall those and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Please press < Alt + F2 > and type/run

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

and see if that gets you what you want. What I suspect is that you may have installed some software at some point that changes which command Unity uses for it's screen locking mechanism. If the command I provided does what you want, then I have two different things you can try.

1. Reinstall gnome-screensaver

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
   sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
   ```
2. If the original command worked as you had hoped but the issue persists after trying solution #1, then open the system settings menu, select the keyboard section, and create a custom keyboard shortcut with that command in it and map it to whatever combination you would like to use to lock your screen.